# Show Metabox Images in slideshow instead of static

Tags: plugin-development, metabox

I am using META BOX plugin from here http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/meta-box.

The images which i add in pluupload uploader , these images show up as static images.
What i need is to show them in a slideshow rather than just static images.

How can i do this, Please help ?

Here is the code i use to call the images added via pluupload metabox in the post.

```
   <?php global $wpdb;
$images = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'rws_plupload', false );
$images = implode( ',' , $images );
// Re-arrange images with 'menu_order'
$images = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
    AND ID in ({$images})
    ORDER BY menu_order ASC
" );
foreach ( $images as $att )
{
    // Get image's source based on size, can be 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large', 'full' or registed post thumbnails sizes
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att, 'full' );
    $src = $src[0];
    // Show image
    echo "<img src='{$src}' />";
}
    ?>
```

Comment: You seem to be lumping together multiple issues - image not showing in back end, image showing as plain link (where?), needing to implement slider. Please try to focus questions on one thing at a time. Also slideshows are a broad topic with myriad of different scripts and implementations, you are unlikely to get answers for that without providing some starting point and clear description of issues and requirements.

Comment: please check now.